# jquery make default navbar button active

Tags: css, button, default, highlight

On opening a page, I want button1 to have the active status so that it lights up. (color white)
So that it is clear that the content shown underneath the navbar is part of that activated button.
After that if I press any of the other navbar buttons I want the default activated button to be off.

I came across the following jquery:

```
$('aheader1').addClass('active')
```

however when I add .active in the css this doesn't change anything.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small_wrapper1"> 
    <th class="header1"><a id="aheader11" ">Button1</a></th>
    <th  class="header2"><a id="aheader21" ">Button2</a></th>
    <th class="header3"><a id="aheader31">Button3</a></th>
```

Comment: Have you try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192921/change-the-color-of-anchor-when-clicked/50193188#50193188

Comment: your answer actually gave me the full solution as it allows me to load all the elements and then turn one on and the rest off. Which was exactly what I was looking for thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="small_wrapper1">
    <span class="header1"><a id="aheader11" >Button1</a></span>
    <span class="header2"><a id="aheader21" >Button2</a></span>
    <span class="header3"><a id="aheader31">Button3</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code as is doesn't quite work. In order to select an element by ID you need to add the '#' symbol in front and make sure to spell the ID correctly. In this case your jQuery selection would look like this `$('#aheader11').addClass('active')`

```js
$('#aheader11').addClass('active')

//this will make Button 1 white (pretty much invisible unless the background is something other than white
```

```css
.active{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small_wrapper1"> 
    <th class="header1"><a id="aheader11">Button1</a></th>
    <th  class="header2"><a id="aheader21">Button2</a></th>
    <th class="header3"><a id="aheader31">Button3</a></th>
```